# How can I recalculate an attribute based on overlap with another layer?

Tags: qgis, srtm

I have 2 layers: The first one is a point Layer (converted from SRTM) with height information. The second one is a polygon layer (shows the forest).

I want to reduce the height value - let's say about 15m if the point value is in a forest area. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the 'SRTM' layer actually a point layer converted from raster, or is it still a raster layer?

Comment: its a point layer. I´ve converted it with surfer11

Comment: @alexserboulykzsi, if the answre provided below gave you the answer you needed, please click the "checkmark" next to the answer to accept it and close teh question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a new point layer that contains information about overlapping forest areas. If your point layer has an attribute 'height' and each forest polygon an attribute 'forest' which is 1 for all forest areas:

1. Select Vector|Data Management Tools|Join attributes by location;
2. Select the point layer as the 'target vector layer' and the polygon as the 'join vector layer';
3. Make sure to select 'keep all records' so you keep all your points;
4. Enter an output shapefile (like points_forestoverlap.shp) and click 'ok'; add to the TOC (layers).
   [image]

   Your new points layer will have a 'forest' attribute - forest areas will be 1 (or whatever value was in the polygon layer) and all non-overlapping points will have NULL. I have not found a way to do calculations using 'NULL' in the field calculator so you have to replace these with 0:
5. Open the attribute table and click the 'forest' column heading to sort it;
6. Select all the rows with NULL under 'forest';
7. Start editing, then open the field calculator;
8. Keep 'Only update selected features', and select 'Update existing field', and select 'forest' in the dropdown box;
9. Enter 0 in the Expression text box and click OK - all the NULLS are replaced by 0.
10. Open the field calculator again, deselect 'Only update selected features', and create a new field new_heights (decimal);
11. Enter the expression `"height" - (("forest" = 1) * 15)` then OK; this will test if it's a forest area ("forest" =1), returning 1, and multiplying by your correction factor.
    [image]

You could also (in step 6) choose to update the existing heights field, and use the same expression.

I suspect you're doing this to correct for canopy height in a forest area? You could have a 'canopy' attribute in your forest polygon and use **that** to do your correction, thus you could have different canopy heights for different forest areas.

Comment: if you go to options > general, you can set 'Representation for null value' to whatever you want eg. '0'

Comment: That does change the __representation__ - but unfortunately any calculation that even looks at a null value still returns null! Just tried this substituting -9999 for NULL and doing a test ("attribute" = -9999) gives -9999 instead of 1 as result.